# Need to output 1095 fields in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm writing an application that requires 3 inputs a day for every day of the year. (3*365=1095). I'm struggling with a way to output each field in an efficient manner.

The inputs are not all-or-nothing (you could fill in 10 days worth of input, hit save, and come back later to fill in more)

I attempted to do this by building all 1095 objects in the controller and then outputting the inputs in the view, but obviously this is really slow and probably memory intensive.

Any suggestions? I'm leaning toward writing the entire form client-side and then filling in the existing elements using AJAX.

EDIT

The model is called Timing and has these attributes:
`month, day, time1, time2, time3`
so there are 365 models to be saved.

Comment: If you dont need to query any of the inner data and just need to store it than you might get away with just serializing the data in a big hash and storing it a `text` field. This would be pretty fast to prototype. Later you could actually break it out into distinct rows/columns, etc.

Comment: If you're using Postgres than you could store it in an `hstore` field which would allow you to query the inner data by fixed keys. `hstore` is basically a serialized hash but its queryable by keys and values.

Comment: Describe the database structure you're intending.  One record holds all 1095 items?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear: I edited the question and clarified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@DVG's answer probably works fine, but it keeps all of the work on the server.

What I ended up going with was my initial thought: get all of the existing timings like this:

```
def edit
  @timings = Timing.find_by_store_id(params[:store_id])
end
```

then in the view, I wrote two javascript functions: one that writes all 365 rows with all 3 columns. Once the field were all output in Javascript, I used another function that took the existing records and inserted them into the form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateForm(){
 timings = <%= @timings.to_json %>;
 ... fill out the fields ...
}
</script>
```

It works nice and fast, and best of all, no AJAX calls. Of course one caveat is that this fails if the user has Javascript disabled, but that's not an issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you've got a nested resource. You have a resource called timing which contains a resource called, what, day?

```
#routes
resources :timing do
  resources :day
end
```

So assuming that when timing is created, you have all 365 days created as well (sounds like a pretty expensive operation). Displaying the fields isn't that tricky. You could just do

```
#controller
def show
  @timings = Timing.all
end

#view
(Date.beginning_of_year..Date.end_of_year).each do |day|
  t = @timings.find { |timing| timing.date == day } #or some other method of deciding that the current day has a timing
  unless t.nil?
    form_for t #etc
  else
    form_for Timing.new #etc
  end
end
```

Then perhaps you could make each for submit via UJS and call it a day. Though this sounds like a pretty complicated design, but I'm not sure what your problem area is.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding my problem. Say I have a Store model. Each store has up to 365 timings. Each timing has 5 fields that need to be input. I'm creating a page that allows you to edit all 365 timings at the same time. What you mentioned might work, but the problem is that it wouldn't show timings that haven't been created yet.

Comment: So which 365 days are we talking about here, the current year?

Comment: Well it doesn't really matter, the user just enters the 3 fields for each timing. Each timing corresponds to a day of the year.

Comment: Well, if it's the current year, you can just make a range of dates for the current year and check your @timings object to see if one already exists on a given day. This will be a super expensive operation, but I don't really know how you'll get around that doing what you're doing. Updated my answer with a "no test" shot at implementing it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want a way to dynamically show time inputs, 3 of them per day, on a form.

If the above is correct, what I would suggest is that you do the nested resource as @DVG has detailed, and load the current day **only**. If you need to load multiple days, you can easily request that through UJS (Ajax) and load it on the same page.

What you probably want to do, in order not to melt down the server, is auto-save the time inputs or auto-save each day's time inputs when the grouping loses focus.